# Why Electric field is same in a cross section of wire even if we change its thickness?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

how does E remains same for the increased thickness. E is determined by field lines, if there is fixed number of field lines coming in then how it gets increased by increasing thickness of wire? To make your explanations more correct make sure that they support the fact that Electricity has a speed of C (speed of light), the speed of signal(Note: it is not the speed of electrons!)

Comment: Please clarify: is the conductor directly connecting both terminals of the battery or is the conductor just part of a circuit (if so then provide details). Also, do you want to talk about ideal batteries or realistic ones?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to measure the E-field? Given this is apparently a DC situation, the electrons will distribute themselves on the surface of the conductor, but the amount of current depends on the total resistance in the circuit.

Comment: @Carl Withoft  distribution of charges will take a long process which is not fast as light. But we want the electric signal at the speed of light. do you know what the speed of electricity is? Can you explain how distribution of charge in circuit takes place at C speed?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field inside a wire depends upon the the current density according to the microscopic version of Ohm's Law.

$$\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$$

where $\vec{J}$ is the current density, and $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the material of which the wire is composed.

If the cross section of the wire is increased, the current density will go down, and as the conductive material's conductivity does not change, the electric field must go down as well.

Comment: If the conductor is attached to a battery then the voltage is fixed by the battery EMF

Comment: @Dale The electric field in a conductor is fixed by microscopic Ohm's law. The emf of a battery is dropped over the entire circuit loop.

Comment: I think that you and I are envisioning different circuits. I am thinking of the conductor connecting the two terminals of the battery (current doubles), and it appears that you are thinking of the conductor simply connecting the battery to some other unspecified circuit components (current unchanged). I have asked the OP for clarification, but no response yet.

Comment: @Dale. It doesn't matter how the wires are connected. The electric field inside the wire is still governed by microscopic Ohm's Law.

Comment: @MathIsBusy it does matter. Yes, microscopic Ohms law must be satisfied, but it is not the only governing equation. If the conductor is directly placed across the terminals then the voltage across the conductor is the same (from the battery) and therefore E is the same. Then by Ohms law J is the same so I is double. You are instead assuming that I is the same so J goes down and therefore E goes down. That would be correct if the conductor is a connection from one terminal to a large fixed resistance circuit. It certainly does matter.

Comment: @Dale. You may be confusing voltage with electric field. The voltage where the wire connects with the battery will be the same as that of the battery. However, assuming the other end of wire is connected to the other battery terminal, the E field in the wire will depend on the length and width of the wire. These will determine the total resistance, current, current density and E field. The E field in a wire may be very different from E field in battery terminal. (Think automotive battery and 22 AWG wire. Thinner wire, higher current density.)

Comment: said “assuming the other end of wire is connected to the other battery terminal, the E field in the wire will depend on the length and width of the wire”. This is incorrect. The E field inside the wire depends on my on the length of the wire, not it’s thickness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125015/discussion-between-dale-and-math-keeps-me-busy).